# django modelForm not validating added foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have a modelForm where I overwritte the **init** method to provide a predefined value from a FK. However when validating the form with the method is_valid() it fails as it says "Palabras" already exists but is not taking in consideration the FK "fk_funcion" as both are PK.

**Models.py**

```py
class Palabras(models.Model):
    fk_funcion = models.ForeignKey(Funcion, related_name='funcion', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    palabra = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    porcentaje = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("fk_funcion", "palabra"),

    def __str__(self):
        return self.palabra
```

**Forms.py**

```py
class PalabraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Palabras
        fields = ('palabra','porcentaje', "fk_funcion")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fk_funcion = kwargs.pop('fk_funcion','')
        super(PalabraForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['fk_funcion']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Funcion.objects.filter(id=fk_funcion))
```

**Views.py**

```py
def create_palabra(request, pk_funcion):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PalabraForm(request.POST,fk_funcion=pk_funcion,,initial={'fk_funcion':pk_funcion}) #I have tried with and without the initial value
        if form.is_valid():
            #Some action
```

What do I have to modify in order to make the form to validate both "palabra" and "fk_funcion" in the modelForm.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've marked `palabra` as `unique=True`. If you only want it to be unique together with the `fk_function`, then remove that and rely on the `unique_together` constraint.

(Also it doesn't make sense for `fk_function` to be both a parameter to the form and a field on that form. You should probably remove it from the list of fields.)

Comment: thanks @daniel removing the `unique=True` actually fixed it.